# Possible to display a button only if user are login?

Tags: login

I have a class "rty-downloads" I want this class to displayed only for WordPress login users, is that possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, post your code, pls.

Comment: yes possible this this in WordPress please send code

Comment: <?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    //show the post
} else {
   //continue as normal
}
?>

Answer (score 6):

You can use this on any WordPress page / template.

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>
    //Code for only logged in users
<?php endif; ?>
```

Checkout the docs for more info: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/

Comment: very helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution: You can use pure css like so:

```
.button-class {display: none;}
.logged-in .button-class {display: block;}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me only works

```
/* show blog button only if logged in */
li.button-class {
    visibility: hidden !important;
    display: none !important;
}
.logged-in li.button-class { 
    visibility: visible !important;
    display: inline-block !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 add_action( 'loop_start',      'your_function' );
 function your_function() {

 if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
echo '<li id="text-2" class="hide">';
} else {
echo '<li id="text-2">'; 
}}
```

Comment: Why `loop_start`?

Comment: I have try it but not seems to work, the easy way could be a function that checks if user are login to display this class "rty-downloads"

Thanks in advance

Comment: yes replace, your class and css code into this function

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use:

**functions.php** (in child theme):

```
add_action('shutdown', function() {
    $final = '';
    $levels = ob_get_level();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $levels; $i++)
    {
        $final .= ob_get_clean();
    }
    echo apply_filters('final_output', $final);
}, 0);

add_filter('final_output', function($output) {
  $display1 = 'none';
  $display2 = 'block';

  if(is_user_logged_in()) {
    $display1 = 'block';
    $display2 = 'none';
  }

  $from = array('%display1%', '%display2%');
  $to = array($display1, $display2);
  $output = str_replace($from,$to,$output);

  return $output;
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.for-logged-in-users {
display: %display1%;
}
.for-logged-out-users {
display: %display2%;
}
```

Then you can just add these two class names for the elements that you want to display/hide.
This way you can display/hide any elements based on any logic.

Comment: final_output isn't a core WordPress filter I don't think? Is that from your cache plugin or similar? How does it filter the CSS which is usually served statically by the web server?

Comment: I'm also not sure there's a benefit of doing it this way over the pure CSS solution using the body tag logged-in class which WordPress already generates.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to insert the add_action part, I've corrected it :)

Comment: I don't really understand the pure css solution, can you explain it?

Comment: If you're logged in to the site then WordPress puts a class 'logged-in' on the body tag. The CSS selector `body.logged-in .for-logged-in-users` means elements that have class for-logged-in-users that are below a body tag with the logged-in class, and given a choice of matching elements CSS will give the most specific one priority. So you can do `.for-logged-in-users { display: none; }` to hide those elements by default and also `body.logged-in .for-logged-in-users { display: block; }` so that if there's the logged-in class on the body tag we override the display: none with display: block.

Comment: I see, that's a better solution, indeed, thanks for explaining it.
However, I have other CSS classes and other unique texts that are needed to be modified/replaced based on more complex conditions, so for me it makes more sense to modify also these classes with this PHP function.